# How to perform the with jquery,ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$('.btn-default').click(function(){
    var values = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "cart_ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: values ,
    success: function (response) {
      consol.log(response);              

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

php code below

```
$number=$_POST['values'];
echo json_encode($number);
```

output show below

[image]

Comment: You have a parse error, so what you're returning isn't valid JSON. It says "unexpected token < at ...", meaning you probably echo HTML in your cart_ajax.php file before the JSON, or there's an error.

Comment: change `data` to `data: "values="+values,`

Comment: It show the error
product_view.php?pid=1&product_name=Pickle&cat_id=1&catname=Amla pickle:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: consol is not defined
    at Object.success (product_view.php?pid=1&product_name=Pickle&cat_id=1&catname=Amla pickle:46)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: change `consol.log(response);` to `console.log(response);`

Comment: Thank you its work,
Now another issue rise

Comment: Now another issue rise-When i click on button having btn-default class at that time value of that button is transfer to cart_ajax.php. suppose first time i click on button and value is 1 and it given the response as 1.but i expecting that when i click the next time the value is 2 and so on..and expecting output show in console.log is 1,2,3....and plz all changes made in cart_ajax.php file not in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line : `data: values ,`

with this : `data: { 'values' : values }`

```
$('.btn-default').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "cart_ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:{ 'values' : $(this).val()},
    success: function (response) {
      consol.log(response);              

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
```